# What SAS function can I use to combine these if-then statements?

Tags: sas

```
data cervical3;
    set cervical2;
    if R_Risk <5.00 then rriskgroup=1;
    else if 5.01 < R_Risk <=10.00 then rriskgroup=2;
    else rriskgroup=3;      
run;
data cervical4;
    set cervical2;
    if P_Risk <5.00 then priskgroup=1;
    else if 5.01 < P_Risk <=10.00 then priskgroup=2;
    else priskgroup=3;
run;
```

I am looking to combine cervical3 with cervical4

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?  Just remove these three statement from the middle `run;data cervical4;set cervical2;`   And now cervical3 will have both new variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create both columns in a single data step, no need to combine both tables.

Also what happens if `r_risk = 5`? In your case the riskgroup assigned would be 3, not sure if this is intended. In the below example I assign it to group 1.

```
data want;
set cervical2;
rriskgroup = ifn(r_risk <= 5, 1, ifn(5 < r_risk <= 10, 2, 3));
priskgroup = ifn(p_risk <= 5, 1, ifn(5 < p_risk <= 10, 2, 3));
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Few methods beyond the IFN simplication - which doesn't scale if you have more than 2.

- Combine the steps into one

```
data cervical3;
    set cervical2;
    if R_Risk <5.00 then rriskgroup=1;
    else if 5.01 < R_Risk <=10.00 then rriskgroup=2;
    else rriskgroup=3;      

    if P_Risk <5.00 then priskgroup=1;
    else if 5.01 < P_Risk <=10.00 then priskgroup=2;
    else priskgroup=3;
run;
```

- Use an array instead, if you have more than 2 this scales well

```
data cervical3;
    set cervical2;

    array scores(2) r_risk p_risk;
    array groups(2) rriskgroup priskgroup;
 
    do i=1 to dim(scores);
    if scores(i)<5.00 then groups(i)=1;
    else if 5.01 < scores(i) <=10.00 then groups(i)=2;
    else groups(i)=3;      

    end;
run;
```

- IMO optimal solution is a format paired with the array method.

```
proc format;
invalue risk_cat_fmt (fuzz=0)
low - 5 = 1
5 <- 10 = 2
10 <- high = 3;
run;

*apply format - no recoding;
proc print data=cervical2 (obs=10);
var r_risk p_risk;
format r_risk p_risk risk_cat_fmt.;
run;

*recoded values;
data cervical3;
    set cervical2;

    array scores(2) r_risk p_risk;
    array groups(2) rriskgroup priskgroup;
 
    do i=1 to dim(scores);
        groups(i) = input(scores(i), risk_cat_fmt.);     
     end;
run;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you define GROUPS array as character since you are assigning character strings to it?  Or perhaps wrap the PUT() in an INPUT() to convert the formatted values into numbers.

Comment: Should probably be an informat instead....

Comment: Not possible to go directly from numbers to numbers.  Informats convert from text, Formats convert to text.